# How can a spellcaster effectively fight against a creature with magic resistance?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

I would like to know how a wizard or some sort of spellcaster can fight against a creature or npc that has the following ability:

> You have advantage on saving throws against spells and
>   other magical effects.

Which can be obtained by the boon of magical resistance, magic items such as the Staff of the magi, etc.

I would like to ask if there is a way for a PC spell caster to balance or nullify the effects of a creature getting advantage on saving throws against spells and other magical effects in order for the wizard to be able to survive or even win a battle against them.

Comment: While I understand the desire for a blanket case scenario, this might be very dependent on the creature (or situation) you are talking about. Can you provide a few example situations that we can expand on? Or is it just a humanoid wielding the Staff of the magic?

Comment: I agree with Guy, there are a lot of answers that could be given, but every option will have a counter-measure available. (Fly is only an option against certain creatures, magical items work OK unless there's a magic-suppressing effect around, "beam" spells are useful against some enemies but less so against others) Constraining the scenario more might give you answers that are more applicable to your particular situation.

Comment: I think this can be answered well in the way that @Christopher did, with the various classes of response, and it's not really too broad as a result.  You don't have to list every spell, just the general approaches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Make Attack Rolls

Advantage on saving throws have no impact whatsoever on spells that have attack rolls—or spells that don't require a roll at all (like *magic missile*).

*Scorching ray*, *fire bolt*, *shocking grasp*, *spiritual weapon*, and so many more spells don't require a save and are unaffected by any modifier/bonus to a saving throw.

Additionally, weapon attacks work well, too. High Dex magic users can have a short sword or rapier with a decent attack bonus to hit 'em where the magic don't protect. Combine that with the *true strike* cantrip and you have a pretty good chance of hitting.

### Summon Others to Fight For You

There are many spells available that summon creatures, elementals, fey, undead, and more that can fight your enemies for you. Again, no saving throw means no bonus.

### Rely on Allies

Having allies who don't use magic also increases your survivability.

### Run the Heck Away

While not a way to fight someone, running away from a losing battle means you can be better prepared for the next encounter!

Spells like *absorb elements* and *blade ward* can mitigate the damage you take. *Expeditious retreat* and *misty step* can get you out of dodge fast. *Blur*, *mirror image*, and *shield* can help with avoiding damage. *Blink* and *invisibility* allow you to move without being noticed.

Comment: It's a good trait to have for Monsters and Pureblood characters, because it helps diversify both players and DM's out of using 'save vs suck' magic all the time. Attack-based spells are typically lower level, but can be upcast, making them an abundant resource for a caster. 

It also helps to know just WHEN Magic Resistance applies, such as the fact it that while it will help against a Beholder's eye rays (they are both 'magical' and require saving throws), it won't against most gaze attacks or side effects from being hit. It also doesn't protect from supernatural effects, like possession.